# Gerrit: Internal Server Error with java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection

Tags: database, oracle, git, gerrit

From time to time we get Internal Server errors when we push to Gerrit. In the logs we see that the connection the connection is closed before the transaction is completed. (See log below)

We're using an Oracle DB with the following settings:

```
[database]
        type = ORACLE
        poolmaxidle = 16
        database = db/ReviewDB
        port = 1521
        instance = infrapd1
        hostname = HOSTNAME
        connectionpool = true
        username = USERNAME
        poollimit = 32
        dataSourceInterceptorClass = com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.javamelody.MonitoringDataSourceInterceptor
```

In the logs we see errors like these when we get an Internal Server error:

```
[2015-02-13 15:49:51,505] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits : Can't insert change/patchset for PROJECT
com.google.gerrit.server.git.InsertException: Error inserting change/patchset
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$1.apply(ReceiveCommits.java:258)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$1.apply(ReceiveCommits.java:249)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$MappingCheckedFuture.mapException(Futures.java:1672)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCheckedFuture.checkedGet(AbstractCheckedFuture.java:85)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.insertChangesAndPatchSets(ReceiveCommits.java:756)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.processCommands(ReceiveCommits.java:564)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.AsyncReceiveCommits$Worker.run(AsyncReceiveCommits.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.ThreadLocalRequestScopePropagator$1.call(ThreadLocalRequestScopePropagator.java:55)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$1.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:98)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$2.run(RequestScopePropagator.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:364)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.gwtorm.server.OrmException: Cannot set auto commit mode
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCheckedFuture.checkedGet(AbstractCheckedFuture.java:78)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: com.google.gwtorm.server.OrmException: Cannot set auto commit mode
        at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcSchema.rollback(JdbcSchema.java:80)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.change.ChangeInserter.insert(ChangeInserter.java:177)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest.insertChange(ReceiveCommits.java:1585)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest.access$800(ReceiveCommits.java:1520)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest$1.call(ReceiveCommits.java:1551)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest$1.call(ReceiveCommits.java:1547)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$1.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:132)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:58)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$CreateRequest.insertChange(ReceiveCommits.java:1546)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.insertChangesAndPatchSets(ReceiveCommits.java:752)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:3790)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:188)
        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcSchema.rollback(JdbcSchema.java:78)
        ... 28 more
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Any advise on how to improve the DB settings or debug the error? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: The `AUTOCOMMIT ON` command in sqlplus may help you

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, or fixes the root cause. To me it looks like the connection is dropped causing the commit to fail (to set autocommit). Since the git push returns immediately it looks like the connection it gets from the pool is not valid. This probably implies that this has to be resolved in the application (testing for a valid connection before trying to commit). It would be nice if I could fix this without having to change the code. So maybe the question is "How do I keep the connections valid/how do I make sure Gerrit only uses valid connections?" Any ideas...?